# armclang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-usage' and '-fdump-ipa-cgraph'

Tags: arm, armclang

I am trying to compile the source files using the flags `-fstack-usage` and `-fdump-ipa-cgraph` for armclang to get the information about stack usage and callgraph.

Here is the command I tried,

```
$ armclang -fstack-usage -fdump-ipa-cgraph -o file file.c
```

But I am getting error like this,

> armclang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-usage'
> armclang: error: unknown argument: '-fdump-ipa-cgraph'